# Does $A^m$ being compact imply $A$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $A^m$ is compact for some $m>0$. Does this imply that $A$ is compact?
I think that this is the case because the function $x\to x^{m}$ is continuous for $m>0$ and so the preimage of each compact is compact. So if $A^m(\mathcal{B})$ is compact ($\mathcal{B}$ is the unit ball in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$) then $A(\mathcal{B})$ should be compact and so $A$. Am i mistaken?

Comment: If $f$ is a constant function $f=c$ on any non-compact domain then the preimage of the compact set  $\{c\}$ is not compact. So your argument makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah right. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that all separable Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic. Let $T:\ell^{2} \to \ell^{2}$ map $e_{2n}$ to $e_{2n+1}$ and $e_{2n-1}$ to $0$. [ $(e_n)$ is the usual basis]. Then $T$ is not compact but $T^{2}=0$ is compact.